# Plugin project :path_provider_macos not found. Please update settings.gradle

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

I used path_provider plugin and it shows this error.

```
Plugin project :path_provider_macos not found. Please update settings.gradle.
```

P.S I recently updated flutter.

Answer (score 5):

This is the solution that I had found to fix it.

1. Go to your FlutterSDK folder, then go to
   .pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\
2. Then delete
   path_provider_macos-{version}

Answer (score 1):

Open android folder and go to settings.gradle , modify code to this :

```
include ':app'

def flutterProjectRoot = rootProject.projectDir.parentFile.toPath()

def plugins = new Properties()
def pluginsFile = new File(flutterProjectRoot.toFile(), '.flutter-plugins')
if (pluginsFile.exists()) {
    pluginsFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader -> plugins.load(reader) }
}

plugins.each { name, path ->
    def pluginDirectory = flutterProjectRoot.resolve(path).resolve('android').toFile()
    include ":$name"
    project(":$name").projectDir = pluginDirectory
}
```

I hope this solve your problem !

Comment: why should android settings solve a mac os problem?